# Solr Cloud Document Routing not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am indexing set of documents with a field called 'route_field'. This field has been set as router field also. My collection has 10 shards(e.g shard_1..shard_10), Currently I am unable to route the documents to the desired by router_field population. e.g if router_field is set to 'shard_1', it should be stored into shard_1. I have followed the documentation but the routing does not seem to take place and solr is choosing shards on its own.